# I can not read uploaded csv file in FastAPI

Tags: python, csv, fastapi

I am trying to iterate through a csv file. However, the received file is giving a hard time to read. I searched for this, I could not get a clear solution!

```
@app.get("/uploadsequence/")
async def upload_sequence_form():
    return HTMLResponse("""
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>sequence upload</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>upload sequence .CSV file</h1>
                    <form method='post' action='/uploadsequence/' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        Upload a csv file: <input type='file' name='csv_file'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Upload'>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>
            """)

@app.post("/uploadsequence/")
async def upload_sequence(csv_file: UploadFile = File(...), db = Depends(get_db)):
        csv_file_encoded = TextIOWrapper(csv_file.file, encoding='utf-8')
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file_encoded)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row["Well Type"] in ["RIG MAINTENANCE","RIG MOVE","RIG COMMISSIONING","ABANDONMENT","LEARNINGCURVE"]:
                crud.insert_sequence_record(db=db, row=row,is_drilling=False)
            else:
                crud.insert_sequence_record(db=db, row=row,is_drilling=True)
```

It gives me this error:
`csv_file_encoded = TextIOWrapper(csv_file.file, encoding='utf-8') AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'readable'`

I changed `UploadFile` to `bytes`:

```
@app.post("/uploadsequence/")
async def upload_sequence(csv_file: bytes = File(...), db = Depends(get_db)):
        csv_file_encoded = TextIOWrapper(csv_file, encoding='utf-8')
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file_encoded)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row["Well Type"] in ["RIG MAINTENANCE","RIG MOVE","RIG COMMISSIONING","ABANDONMENT","LEARNINGCURVE"]:
                crud.insert_sequence_record(db=db, row=row,is_drilling=False)
            else:
                crud.insert_sequence_record(db=db, row=row,is_drilling=True)
```

It gives this error: `csv_file_encoded = TextIOWrapper(csv_file, encoding='utf-8') AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'readable'`

I got rid of encoding:

```
@app.post("/uploadsequence/")
async def upload_sequence(csv_file: bytes = File(...), db = Depends(get_db)):
        # csv_file_encoded = TextIOWrapper(csv_file, encoding='utf-8')
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row["Well Type"] in ["RIG MAINTENANCE","RIG MOVE","RIG COMMISSIONING","ABANDONMENT","LEARNINGCURVE"]:
                crud.insert_sequence_record(db=db, row=row,is_drilling=False)
            else:
                crud.insert_sequence_record(db=db, row=row,is_drilling=True)
```

It gives this error:
`self._fieldnames = next(self.reader) _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)`

Comment: In the first case you simply have a `File` object that you can use as a classic file. In the second case, you have the raw bytes. Thus you can't open a file from the file you already have nor by passing the bytes. You could try using the `DictReader` on the spooled file, instead of the bytes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the following to read the csv file. `codecs.iterdecode` worked for me.

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(csv_file.file,'utf-8'))
```

Comment: @Sören It is a standard python library

Comment: Future readers may want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
@app.post("/submitform")
async def handle_form(assignment_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
   print(assignment_file.filename)
   csv_reader = pd.read_csv(assignment_file.file)
   
   print(csv_reader)
   //else return response
   // csv data will be stored in the csv_reader
```

Comment: I think this is method using pandas will be slower than using the standard libraries

Comment: How do you do this without uploading CSV, but reading csv off a path directly from Python?

Comment: i just needed that assignment_file.file 
thanks